# CSS text box lost top line

Tags: html, css, textbox, markup

I need your help to someone explain this. I am creating sign in form, but when I am receiving a validation error, I am getting problem in my text box [input type=text] in html wherein the upper line in the text box is lost. Please see attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSjVr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMu6D.png)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #141517;
}

* {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  padding: 10px 55px 40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type=text],
[type=password] {
  width: 97%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#login {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#signup {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2> Sign In </h1>

      <form action="p1.php" method="POST">
        <div>some validation error</div> Username: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" /> <br/> Password:
        <input type="password" name="password" /> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login" />
      </form>

      <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Create New Account" id="signup" />
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your code so that we can help you out.

Comment: please see the code above

Comment: which css library / framework are you using? Also if you can show us a working example, then it will be easy for us to fix th eissue.

Comment: What HTML is inserted when you receive validation errors? Maybe the dynamically inserted markup is not valid...

Comment: I think it's the problem with my css. I did not enter the height of my div id row but it is intended because i want it to automatically get bigger whenever there is a validation error. I am not using any framework. It is just php, css and html5. Please advise. I do not understand why it behaves that way.

Comment: The code as shown so far is likely not enough, because we don’t know what your `<?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>` actually outputs. Suggest that you start by validating the HTML code your script outputs when those validation errors are shown, to see if you made any mistakes there. https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

I assume your validator inserts a block-level element into your markup, like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #141517;
}

* {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;  /* <-- here is the problem */
  color: #4f4f4f;
  padding: 10px 55px 40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type=text],
[type=password] {
  width: 97%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#login {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#signup {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2> Sign In </h1>

      <form action="p1.php" method="POST">
        <div>some validation error</div> Username: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" /> <br/> Password:
        <input type="password" name="password" /> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login" />
      </form>

      <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Create New Account" id="signup" />
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, the `font-size: 13px;` from `.row` causes the upper border lines of the input elements with `font-size: 16px;` to be hidden by block-level elements, that inherit this smaller font-size from the `.row` above.

**The solution:**

Remove the general font-size definition from `.row` and apply it to the child elements (like your validation `div`) in particular.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #141517;
}

* {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: arial;
  /* font-size: 13px;  <-- here is the problem */
  color: #4f4f4f;
  padding: 10px 55px 40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type=text],
[type=password] {
  width: 97%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#login {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#signup {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2> Sign In </h1>

      <form action="p1.php" method="POST">
        <div>some validation error</div> Username: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" /> <br/> Password:
        <input type="password" name="password" /> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login" />
      </form>

      <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Create New Account" id="signup" />
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help. I would appreciate an accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting it like this:

input[type='text'] {
    Code here
}

Just the type of the input in single quotes.